# How can NRefactory keep the original formatting

Tags: c#, nrefactory

Hi I use NRefactory to extract String constant and remplace it by static variable for i18n, I can successfully do it but when I output my code with GetText() it doesn't keep the original formatting. I want to be do that with the minimum formatting change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Modifying C# code" portion (last section) of the [NRefactory CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code).

Comment: This part contains invalid code. The object "file" is never created, and I can't find any info on what type is it.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov: Download the source code attached to the article to see that code snippet in context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep current formatting you can use `DocumentScript` to apply modifications on AST. It works based in `TextLocation` property stored in syntax tree.
To create a script you need to do this :

```
IDocument document = new StringBuilderDocument("source code");
CSharpFormattingOptions policy = FormattingOptionsFactory.CreateAllman();
var options = new TextEditorOptions();

var script = new DocumentScript(document, policy, options);
```

Now you can use methods like Replace, Remove, InsertAfter and etc. on you AST. It works with both ast nodes as well as offsets.

It also keeps track of modifications, so you don't have to be worry about conflicts on multiple changes.
For more examples on NRefactory you may wanna also check my [blog](http://arashtaher.wordpress.com/tag/nrefactory/).